# ¿Para referirse a un jaguar cuál palabra es la correcta jaguar o yaguar?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Existen dos formas para referirse a un jaguar:

- jaguar
- yaguar

¿Cuál es la palabra correcta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aunque el uso común es [jaguar](http://dle.rae.es/jaguar) la forma correcta es [yaguar](http://dle.rae.es/yaguar). Informacion respecto a esto lo podemos encontrar en [Ceballos y Fernández de Córdoba, Luis. «Dos notas para el Diccionario académico». BRAE, XLVII, 1967, pp. 383-390](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/CeballosFernandezdeCordoba_383_390_Reducido.pdf).

> **JAGUAR**
>
> En cuanto que deba preferirse jaguar a yaguar no estamos de acuerdo, si ha de darse preferencia a la corrección sobre la
>   popularidad; jaguar es lo vulgar y de uso corriente, yaguar es lo
>   correcto. En su magnífica obra sobre "Mamíferos sudamericanos" dice D.
>   Angel Cabrera: "muchas personas, sobre todo aquellas que quieren pasar
>   por cultas, le llaman también jaguar; pero esta palabra escrita así
>   con j inicial debe ser proscrita de la lengua castellana; no es en
>   efecto sino la forma en que los autores franceses, ingleses y alemanes
>   (en cuyos idiomas suena la j como y) han transcrito la voz americana
>   yaguar o yaguara; pero en nuestra lengua, que la j tiene un sonido
>   gutural fuerte, no hay por qué adoptar una grafía que desfigura
>   totalmente la palabra verdadera". Aun aceptada ya jaguar por su
>   extendido uso, procede referir a yaguar y señalar la incorrección.

En mi experiencia, nunca he oido que se diga yaguar así que si uno lo dice quiza la demás gente creera que uno es el que esta equivocado.

Comment: Curioso...solo en ingles lo he escuhado con la y.

Comment: Curioso, alguna vez he escuchado "yaguar" y pensaba que era una pretenciosa pronunciación a la inglesa.

Answer (score 3):

El [Diccionario de la Real Academia Española](http://buscon.rae.es) ofrece una definición para *jaguar*  ("felino americano de hasta dos metros de longitud..."), pero en la entrada de *yaguar* simplemente indica "Véase *jaguar*".  De la misma manera, el [Diccionario Panhispánico de dudas](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd) tiene una entrada para *jaguar* que dice "Esta voz de origen guaraní puede escribirse de dos formas: *jaguar*, grafía mayoritaria en todo el ámbito hispánico [... ] y *yaguar*, grafía usada esporádicamente en el área rioplatense". Al igual que el Diccionario de la RAE, el DPD también contiene una entrada independiente para *yaguar*, que simplemente redirige a *jaguar* sin ofrecer una definición.

Answer (score 3):

De forma adicional a las respuestas previas, podemos aclarar al nivel de pronunciación que, si el animal tiene su nombre de los guaranís, y que hoy en día los guaranís hispanófonos están en Argentina, pues la i-griega no se pronuncia lo mismo que en España (ni, de hecho, en cualquier otro país) sino que se parece más a la jota francesa. 
Hasta peor, en región tucumana (fuerte influencia aborígena) van a escuchar i-griegas bastardas, entre la fuerte r castellana y la jota francesa. Por ejemplo una palabra emblemática para mí de la región es la "yungla". Se refiere a la vegetación local, no es equivalente de "jungle" en inglés pero se pronuncia casi como si fuera la palabra inglesa.

Espero haber brindado algo interesante para ustedes.

Abrazo

Answer (score 1):

Crea lo que crea la gente, ambas son correctas http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/definicion.php?palabra=yaguar